# The import android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider cannot be resolved

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I am trying to use GoogleMap V2 .But i am getting error on import these :

```
import android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider;
import android.support.v7.media.MediaRouteSelector;
import android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter;
import android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter.RouteInfo;
```

And the error is

```
The import android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider cannot be resolved
```

Here is the screen shot of the library that i have added

[image]

What i have to do .I have tried to import **android\support\v7** By Build path .But it is not resolving my issue in there any way so that i can resolve these errors.

Comment: do you see the android-support-v4.jar in the projects libs folder?

Comment: @Raghunandan yes i have that i have imported that one also by build path

Comment: then you error clearly says that is not the case . look at `android-support-v4.jar` from the support library under the sdk and add it to libs folder

Comment: i have already imported android-support-v4.jar and added to the library

Comment: then you will not get the error that you have just mentioned.

Comment: @Raghunandan see i have updated the code with a screenshot

Comment: @GauravPandey Attached image says that you are using wrong jar for v7. Actual path is `<sdk>/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/libs`. Copy both jars from there

Comment: @GauravPandey GridLayout is a library project and must be referenced just like google play services

Comment: @GauravPandey did you reference or add it as a jar file?

Comment: @Raghunandan what u said those import error are gone now it is showing This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of ADT plug-in. Please update ADT plug-in

Comment: @GauravPandey update the adt plugin for eclipse

Comment: @Raghunandan can we chat i have issue in this aap

Comment: @GauravPandey which chat room pls invite

Comment: @Raghunandan i am not getting that option to invite for a chat in this question

Comment: @Raghunandan i am on the both chat

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you have added gridlayout.jar to the projects lib folder.

Its a library project with resources. You need to reference the library project in your android projet

This library is located in the `<sdk>/extras/android/support/v7/gridlayout/` directory after you download the Android Support Libraries.

Follow **Adding libraries with resources**

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res

Answer (score 6):

had the same problem and found that the **link** in my project to the **appcomcat_v7 project** is broken (right-click project and choose properties, then head to the Android tab)...

i removed and then added the correct project and i was good to go...

[image]

Comment: For anyone that is curious, the real project is located in: sdk\extras\android\support\v7

Answer (score 1):

These type of Errors generally occurs when we accidentally  close these libraries(by close unrelated projects,etc) which are automatically generated In Project Explorer of Eclipse like:

- appcompat_v7
- appcompat_v7_2
- appcompat_v7_3
- appcompat_v7_4
- appcompat_v7_5
- appcompat_v7_6
- appcompat_v7_7
- appcompat_v7_8
- appcompat_v7_9
- appcompat_v7_10
- appcompat_v7_11
- appcompat_v7_12
- appcompat_v7_13
- appcompat_v7_14

As soon as I open these files,all the errors in my app were vanished !

If It till then didn't work then do `Project -> Properties -> Android -> Is Library -> Add.. -> And add appcompat_v7_*`

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem to this after I had used force to close Eclipse.

When I then restarted Eclipse, I noticed a number of "appcompat_v7..." folders in my workspace directory. I deleted these - and maybe that was the cause of this problem.

But I resolved it by creating a new Test project in Eclipse, then restarting Eclipse to find all my projects compiled again! :)

I didn't need to change any project properties.

Answer (score 0):

this solution worked for me:

The support library `android-support-v4.jar` cause this conflictand you see the error: `The import android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider cannot be resolved`, just delete the library under /libs folder of your project, because the library is already contained in the library `appcompat_v7`, clean and build your project, and your project will work like a charm!

[image]