# The Import android.support.v7 cannot be resolved

Tags: android, eclipse

I am new to Android. Currently, I have the `adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030.zip` (Windows 32 bit) installed - and have successfully installed the Android SDK and Eclipse. Also, I have updated everything in the Android SDK manager. Now, I am working in Android v-4.4.2

My project runs successfully, but when I import `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;` and `import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;` the project won't debug. I get the error `The Import android.support.v7 cannot be resolved`

I searched in Google and installed `Android Support Library` then added `v7` in my project.

1. File->Import (android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7). Choose "appcompat"
2. Project-> properties->Android. In the section library "Add" and choose "appCompat"

**Screenshot**

[image]

Successfully added in `appCompat` but still I am still getting the error.

Comment: see this link it is can help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21876435/the-import-android-support-v7-app-mediarouteactionprovider-cannot-be-resolved

Comment: You can try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/27114527/3729471<br>Hope it's helps your problem

Answer (score 170, accepted):

1. Go to your project in the navigator, right click on properties.
2. Go to the Java Build Path tab on the left.
3. Go to the libraries tab on top.
4. Click add external jars.
5. Go to your ADT Bundle folder, go to sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/libs.
6. Select the file android-support-v7-appcompat.jar
7. Go to order and export and check the box next to your new jar.
8. Click ok.

Comment: The above solution helped me  import the support v7 files but now i m getting error at R.  as R cannot be resolved to a variable.

Comment: WOW - thank you.  So many explanations import this export that, click button change file -- you nailed.

Comment: @Joyson try to clean your project. I cleaned my project and it's resolve this error.

Comment: How do you get sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/libs?  I've got C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support, but no v7 in that folder.  There's support/appcompat-v7, but it's just full of empty folders with version numbers as the folder names.

Comment: haha, i think we got the same situation here @RoboticRenaissance... because we're eclipse user nor android studio user.

Comment: Nah, I was using Android Studio.  @gumuruh

Answer (score 26):

I tried the answer described here but it doesn´t worked for me.
I have the last Android SDK tools ver. 23.0.2 and Android SDK Platform-tools ver. 20

The support library `android-support-v4.jar` is causing this conflict, just delete the library under `/libs` folder of your project, don´t be scared, the library is already contained in the library `appcompat_v7`, clean and build your project, and your project will work like a charm!

[image]

Comment: It's a really perfect solution, but it difficult situation for beginners

Comment: Worked for me now I have another unresolve import error as -The import android.support.design cannot be resolved

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the auto-generated project **appcompat_v7** was closed. So just open up that project in Package Explorer.

Hope this help.

Comment: Btw, why does this work, Why do we need to open it? Another weird Eclipse bug?

Comment: must be opened if your project has the reference to this library, Properties -> Android -> See if the library is already specified.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue every time I tried to create a new project, but based on the console output, it was because of two versions of android-support-v4 that were different:

```
[2014-10-29 16:31:57 - HeadphoneSplitter] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2014-10-29 16:31:57 - HeadphoneSplitter] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2014-10-29 16:31:57 - HeadphoneSplitter] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2014-10-29 16:31:57 - HeadphoneSplitter] Versions found are:
[2014-10-29 16:31:57 - HeadphoneSplitter] Path: C:\Users\jbaurer\workspace\appcompat_v7\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2014-10-29 16:31:57 - HeadphoneSplitter]   Length: 627582
[2014-10-29 16:31:57 - HeadphoneSplitter]   SHA-1: cb6883d96005bc85b3e868f204507ea5b4fa9bbf
[2014-10-29 16:31:57 - HeadphoneSplitter] Path: C:\Users\jbaurer\workspace\HeadphoneSplitter\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2014-10-29 16:31:57 - HeadphoneSplitter]   Length: 758727
[2014-10-29 16:31:57 - HeadphoneSplitter]   SHA-1: efec67655f6db90757faa37201efcee2a9ec3507
[2014-10-29 16:31:57 - HeadphoneSplitter] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

I don't know a lot about Eclipse. but I simply deleted the copy of the jar file from my project's libs folder so that it would use the appcompat_v7 jar file instead. This fixed my issue.

Comment: Hey see my answer will be useful for you. Your project must contain only one library android-support-v4.jar.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it adding these lines in the build.grandle (App Module)

```
dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) //it was there
   compile "com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+" //Added
   compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+" //Added
}
```

Comment: You do **realize** this is an **Eclipse** related question, **NOT Android Studio** ?

Answer (score 0):

Recent sdk-manager's download does not contain
android-support-v7-appcompat.jar
But the following dir contains aar file
C:\Users\madan\android-sdks\extras\android\m2repository\com\
android\support\appcompat-v7\24.2.1\appcompat-v7-24.2.1.aar
This file can be imported by right-click project, import, 
select general, select archieve and finally select aar file.
Even this does not solve the problem.
Later remove 'import android.R' and add
'import android.support.v7.appcompat.*;' 
Follow this tutorial for other details:
http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/22/android-hello-world-example-using-eclipse-ide-and-android-development-tools-adt-plugin

Answer (score 0):

completing the answer @Jorgesys, in my case it was exactly the same way but the export configuration was missing in the library:

1. right click on appcompat-v7 project;
2. properties;
3. left tab, Java Build Path;
4. Right tab, Order and export;
5. Check classes.jar with appcompat-v7;

[image: export lib]