# Why i can't compile my android project with other APIs

Tags: android, api, compilation

i want to build an android project for API 19 so i choose this API to compile with, but when eclipse create the projects its tells me that some ressources are not found and the R class is not generated. the only way to avoid this errors is to compile with API21

So why i can not use my API 19 in compilation ??

THNKS for all

Comment: are you referencing external classes or frameworks that require a higher API level? Do you have code that requires API level 21?

Comment: i don't think so, every time i create à project i get theses errors even if the project is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile SDK Version can and should always be set to the latest SDK released. It is **target** SDK version that you should set to the latest version you've tested your app on.

Eclipse by default includes [AppCompat](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat) - the part of the Support Library which ensures a consistent look and feel across all API versions v7+ and the newest version, revision 21, compiles against API 21.

Answer (score 0):

```
So why i can not use my API 19 in compilation ?
```

be sure to have the api installed:

`Window` -> `Android SDK Manager`

[image]

Comment: HI, i did but always the same problem. Meybe i must use the leatest APi

Comment: I had that same problem but now with the last sdk, try my answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24998368/the-import-android-support-v7-cannot-be-resolved/26936141#26936141