# Android Support Library causes unresolved R import

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm working on an Eclipse Android project (target SDK 18). Since I wanted to use some Material Design features from Android 5 I added the library project `Design Support Library` (Target SDK 23) to Eclipse and linked it to my project.  This project links to another library project called `Android-support-v7-appcompat`.

I get the following error: **"The import [...].myProject.R cannot be resolved".**

Whenever I remove the support library from my project the error disappears.

Since a lot of people had the same problem before I already tried rebuilding and cleaning the project a couple of times. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24998368/the-import-android-support-v7-cannot-be-resolved) post and added the `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar` to my project. I delted the `support v4 jar` from the `support-v7` `libs` folder. Then I followed [this guide](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/a-comprehensive-troubleshooting-guide-for-androids-r-cannot-be-resolved-error/) and made sure that the `\res` folders didn't contain any errors. Still no success. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Did you change the API build target to match the level of the SDK? 23? Project -> Properties -> Android -> Android Build Target

Comment: Just a reminder, [Eclipse is deprecated](http://android-developers.blogspot.rs/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html)

Comment: Perfect, that's it! I didn't think about that, since I went trough all the trouble to keep my target SDK low. Thanks!